# Elastic Search: match field from a certain place

Tags: elasticsearch

> *"question_tag: elastic search 
> question_content:This is my first question about elastic search on stackoverflow"*

Above is an example field stored in elastic search
I want to know whether phrase "elastic search" exists **after "question_content"**. Is there a way to do this ?

**For example above**, answer should be **yes**.

**For example**

> *"question_tag: elastic search 
> question_content:This is my first question about Java on stackoverflow"*

answer should be **no**.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating two different fields `question_tag` and `question_content`  rather than making things complex by storing everything in a single filed.

So your mapping would look something like this:

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "question_tag": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "question_content": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can the index your docs. For e.g.:

```
PUT myindex/_doc/1
{
  "question_tag": "elastic search",
  "question_content": "This is my first question about elastic search on stackoverflow"
}

PUT myindex/_doc/1
{
  "question_tag": "elastic search",
  "question_content": "This is my first question about Java on stackoverflow"
}
```

Then you can use `match_phrase` query to get the docs having a particular phrase.

```
GET myindex/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match_phrase" : {
         "question_content" : "elastic search"
      }
   }
}
```

More about [match phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html).

Comment: Thank you. In reality, in my work, the field have already being stored in ES for a lone time. If I cut this field into two fields, it will need some extra work. So, I am wondering if I can play on the original field.  Another possibility is to add a new field "question_content" and keep the orginal field unchanged, however the down side is it will cost more disk spaces.

Comment: You can use scroll and bulk api to reindex data (this will be fast) to the new fields and while doing so set the value of existing field to null. This will solve the problem of disk space as well.